# Resharper states if/else condition will never be hit, why?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, visual-studio-2015, resharper

I have this code from a PushSharp example which details how to handle exceptions. For some reason all the `else` conditions are greyed out by Resharper, stating that `The expression is always false`. I don't see how this is possible.

```
// ex is an Exception passed in to the method
if (ex is NotificationException)
{
    // Deal with the failed notification
    var notification = ((NotificationException)ex).Notification;
    var logItem = new PushLog($"{typePrefix} Notification failed", $"Notification Failed: {notification}");
    _pushLogRepo.Insert(logItem);
}
else if (ex is DeviceSubscriptionExpiredException) // Resharper says this is always false
{
   // exception handling code...
}
else if (ex is RetryAfterException) // Resharper says this is always false
{
   // exception handling code...
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("Notification Failed for some (Unknown Reason)");
}
```

Can someone explain how this is possible? I don't see how it can be. Here's a screenshot from VS2015 which is a bit clearer with syntax highlighting - ignore the error, I'm in the middle of refactoring.

[image]

Comment: What kind of exception is it being passed in? What's passing it?

Comment: It's a plain old `Exception`. It's being provided by an error handling method provided by a library I'm using.

Comment: that library might only throw a certain type of exception, even if it's coming in as generic.

Or it could be a resharper error. who knows.

Comment: Yeah, Slaks got it - it only throws exceptions which are derived from a base class of which the first `if` statement traps, hence the problem. C# 101. Should have spotted it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This would happen if those classes inherit `NotificationException`, since then the first branch would always hit.

Comment: *[Bangs head]* Of course. You're right. Should have noticed that. For proof: https://github.com/Redth/PushSharp/blob/master/PushSharp.Core/Exceptions.cs. Thanks